# Identifying the type of wallet that's being used?

Tags: wallet, address

Is there any way to identify what type of a wallet a Bitcoin address is associated with?

For example, if you created an address via Blockchain.info, would anyone know it was created through them or know that you're wallet was located there?

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot identify what wallet software was used to create an address. This is impossible to do as all addresses are the same type of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify some types of wallets by their behaviour, say using uncompressed keys rather than compressed ones, but this isn’t something directly revealed by any transaction. There is no specific need to expose this sort of data, and every reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Explanation: A service creating a vanity address (or compressed / uncompressed keys as mentioned above) would be things that might give you a hint as to what created it.

Ultimately, even if there are hints, there is no mechanism in bitcoin addresses to determine who created an address with any meaningful certainty. Addresses are entirely math based and contain no other "meta" data.